# TinyMCE: Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible frame "content_ifr"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tinymce, capybara, tinymce-rails

In a Capybara feature spec, I am attempting to do the following:

```rb
  within_frame("element_content_content_ifr") do
    # do stuff
  end
```

Where `element_content_content_ifr` is the CSS ID of my tinymce iframe.

I get the error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible frame "element_content_content_ifr"
```

I've set a pause during the test and inspected element. The iframe with the specified ID is definitely there, but Capybara can't find it. I am not having issues with Capybara finding iframes in other parts of my application, only the TinyMCE iframe.

I have also attempted `sleep 5` before executing the `within_frame` line, but I get the same error. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there a proper way to do Capybara tests when TinyMCE is on the page?

Attached is a screenshot of the iframe's visibility on the page, as well as its DOM ancestors:
[image: screenshot of DOM elements]

Comment: Are you sure the "element_content_content_ifr" iframe isn't nested  inside another iframe? Also does the iframe have any size on the page? If those pointers don't lead to an answer - add the relevant HTML or screen shot of DOM inspection.

Comment: The iframe is definitely not within another iframe, although it is within a form, does that affect anything? The size is an interesting question. I'm not sure it has a size when there isn't any content, but there is when content is entered. Thanks for the lead, I'll let you know if it brings me to a solution.

Comment: I looked into it and the iframe is 936x156 (based on device's current size), so the iframe definitely should be visible.

Comment: Please add the HTML or a screenshot of the DOM inspection showing the iframe and its ancestors

Comment: Also - make sure you're not calling the `within_frame` while you're scoped to an element that doesn't contain the iframe (if you are scoped).

Comment: @ThomasWalpole see updated post. Re: scoping, it is not currently scoped in anything.

Comment: Hmmm -- there's an ancestor div with `visibility: hidden' style -- It's possible that's screwing up the visibility algorithm

Comment: That's definitely a strong lead. Will have to test later, I have a meeting in 4 minutes!

Comment: Looking at the HTML and CSS that's shown in the screenshot I'm actually really confused as to why the iframe is visible at all -- maybe some kind of interaction between visibility and flexbox or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the HTML/CSS shown it's confusing how the iframe is shown at all since its ancestor `<div role="application" ...>` has visibility: "hidden" as a style and there isn't a visible override of that anywhere below. First thing would be to make sure you're running a recent version of Capybara and whatever driver you're using (I assume selenium). If you already are, or that doesn't fix the issue you can try working around it with

```
within_frame("element_content_content_ifr", visible: false) do
```

and see if that works.

Beyond that if you can figure out what CSS is making the frame actually visible while inside the hidden element, I would appreciate it if you could file an issue on the Capybara project with enough info to replicate the issue.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. The `visible: false` helped me move forward. I'm actually quite confused as well why I'm able to see elements that are nested in a hidden element. As far as I'm concerned, it's TinyMCE magic that I have officially run out of time investigating further. That being said, I'm more than happy to file an issue if you want me to. I wonder if this is more something that's under the wheelhouse `tinymce-rails`.